# Signature tab is not visible when envelope is created from template

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

For below requirements We wanted to use DocuSign for SalesForce:
 1. Internal user, clicks a button on page layout which trigger DocuSign
 2. Community user, clicks a button on VF page which triggers DocuSign

To do this, I have connected both salesforce and Docusign accounts. And done basic configuration like hooking up custom variables between DocuSign and SalesForce, creating template using pdf and some tabs like **Signature**, **Initial** and **Date Signed**. Let say template ID is `aa3d9632-1595-4fef-87dd-1795334edf9d`.

Now, for 1st requirement from above, I have created a JavaScript button on page layout which is using created template `aa3d9632-1595-4fef-87dd-1795334edf9d`. Here, when an internal user clicks on button, recipient can see all tabs (**Signature**, **Initial** and **Date Signed**) which were included in template.

For 2nd requirement, I am using SOAP API to trigger DocuSign. As I am already having a template `aa3d9632-1595-4fef-87dd-1795334edf9d`, I wanted to use the same in my 2nd requirement as well. To do so, I am using `CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates()` method please below piece of code:

```
//Step #1) Buiding Template, Recipient and Envelope information
// 1.1) Put the created template from DocuSign

DocuSignAPI.TemplateReference templetRef = new DocuSignAPI.TemplateReference();
templetRef.Template = aa3d9632-1595-4fef-87dd-1795334edf9d;
templetRef.TemplateLocation = 'Server';

DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfTemplateReference templetRefs = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfTemplateReference();
templetRefs.TemplateReference = new DocuSignAPI.TemplateReference[]{templetRef};
system.debug('templetRefs: '+templetRefs);

// 1.2) Create a Recipient
DocuSignAPI.Recipient recipient = new DocuSignAPI.Recipient();
recipient.Email         = docuSign_email;
recipient.UserName      = docuSign_fName+' '+docuSign_lName;
recipient.Type_x        = 'Signer';
recipient.ID            = 1;
recipient.RoutingOrder  = 1; 
recipient.RequireIDLookup = false;

DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfRecipient1 recipients = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfRecipient1();
recipients.Recipient = new DocuSignAPI.Recipient[]{recipient};

system.debug('recipients: '+recipients);           


// 1.3) Construct the envelope information
DocuSignAPI.EnvelopeInformation envelopeInfo = new DocuSignAPI.EnvelopeInformation();
envelopeInfo.Subject    = 'Terms of Agreement for your Signature';
envelopeInfo.EmailBlurb = 'We are sending you this request for your electronic signature, please review and electronically sign by following the link above. ';
envelopeInfo.AccountId  = accountId;

//Populate Application as a Custom Field in Envelope
DocuSignAPI.CustomField custFiled = new DocuSignAPI.CustomField();
custFiled.Name      = 'DSFSSourceObjectId';
custFiled.Value     = docuSign_appID;
custFiled.show      = 'False';
custFiled.Required  = 'True';
custFiled.CustomFieldType = 'Text';

DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfCustomField CustFields = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfCustomField();
//CustFields.CustomField = new DocuSignAPI.CustomField[]{custFiled,accFiled};
CustFields.CustomField = new DocuSignAPI.CustomField[]{custFiled};

envelopeInfo.CustomFields = CustFields;             

system.debug('envelopeInfo: '+envelopeInfo);

// Step #2) Create a Envelope with informtion created from step #1 and SendEnvelope
System.debug('Calling the API');

//DocuSignAPI.EnvelopeStatus es  = dsApiSend.CreateAndSendEnvelope(envelope);
DocuSignAPI.EnvelopeStatus envelopStatus = dsApiSend.CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates(templetRefs, recipients,envelopeInfo,true);
envelopeId = envelopStatus.EnvelopeID;
```

In this case, recipient not able to see any tab (**Signature**, **Initial** and **Date Signed**) which were included in template.

Strangely these tabs are visible when user click on page layout JavaScript button click, but not on VF page button click.

Comment: Please share your envelope creation code. It is difficult to tell without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to map your recipient to your template role

Here is the code snippet that needs to be updated.

- I have set the recipient roleName `recipient.RoleName = 'Signer 1'`
- created the ArrayOfTemplateReferenceRoleAssignment and added to the TemplateReference.

See complete code [here](https://gist.github.com/codingdawg/36be275685d0d09e3a0140e2a4d929e6/#file-soapcreateenvelopefromtemplate-java-L22-L33)

```
 // 1.2) Create a Recipient
 DocuSignAPI.Recipient recipient = new DocuSignAPI.Recipient();
 recipient.Email         = docuSign_email;
 recipient.UserName      = docuSign_fName+' '+docuSign_lName;
 recipient.Type_x        = 'Signer';
 recipient.ID            = 1;
 recipient.RoutingOrder  = 1; 
 recipient.RequireIDLookup = false;
 recipient.RoleName = 'Signer 1';

 DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfRecipient1 recipients = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfRecipient1();
 recipients.Recipient = new DocuSignAPI.Recipient[]{recipient};


 ArrayOfTemplateReferenceRoleAssignment tras = new ArrayOfTemplateReferenceRoleAssignment();
 TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment assign = new TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment();
 assign.setRoleName(recipient.getRoleName());
 assign.setRecipientID(recipient.getID());
 tras.getRoleAssignment().add(assign);
 templetRef.setRoleAssignments(tras);
```